# Deserialize XMLDocument with encoded characters in attribute names

Tags: sharepoint, c#-3.0, character, xml-deserialization

I'm Trying to deserialize xml data into an object with c#. I have always done this using the .NET deserialize method, and that has worked well for most of what I have needed.

Now though, I have XML that is created by Sharepoint and the attribute names of the data I need to deserialize have encoded caracters, namely:

*space, º, ç ã, :, * and a *hyphen* as
*x0020*, *x00ba*, *x007a*, *x00e3*, *x003a* and *x002d* respectivly

I'm trying to figure out what I have to put in the attributeName parameter in the properties XmlAttribute

*x0020* converts to a space well, so, for instance, I can use

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ows_Nome Completo")]
```

to read

```
ows_Nome_x0020_Completo="MARIA..."
```

On The other hand, neither

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ows_Motiva_x00e7__x00e3_o_x003a_")]
```

nor

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ows_Motivação_x003a_")]
```

nor

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ows_Motivação:")]
```

allow me to read

```
ows_Motiva_x00e7__x00e3_o_x003a_="text to read..."
```

With the first two I get no value returned, and the third gives me a runtime error for invalid caracters (the colon).

Anyway to get this working with .NET Deserialize, or do I have to build a specific deserializer for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at (the "cryptic" data) is called XML entities. It's used by SharePoint to safekeep attribute names and similar elements.

There are a few ways of dealing with this, the most elegant ways to solve it is by extracting the List schema and match the element towards the schema. The schema contain all meta-data about your list data. A polished example of a Schema can be seen below or here http://www.bendsoft.com/documentation/camelot-php-tools/1_5/packets/schema-and-content-packets/schemas/example-list-view-schema/

If you don't want to walk that path you could start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35577sxd.aspx

```
<Field Name="ContentType">
  <ID>c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d</ID>
  <DisplayName>Content Type</DisplayName>
  <Type>Text</Type>
  <Required>False</Required>
  <ReadOnly>True</ReadOnly>
  <PrimaryKey>False</PrimaryKey>
  <Percentage>False</Percentage>
  <RichText>False</RichText>
  <VisibleInView>True</VisibleInView>
  <AppendOnly>False</AppendOnly>
  <FillInChoice>False</FillInChoice>
  <HTMLEncode>False</HTMLEncode>
  <Mult>False</Mult>
  <Filterable>True</Filterable>
  <Sortable>True</Sortable>
  <Group>_Hidden</Group>
</Field>
<Field Name="Title">
  <ID>fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247</ID>
  <DisplayName>Title</DisplayName>
  <Type>Text</Type>
  <Required>True</Required>
  <ReadOnly>False</ReadOnly>
  <PrimaryKey>False</PrimaryKey>
  <Percentage>False</Percentage>
  <RichText>False</RichText>
  <VisibleInView>True</VisibleInView>
  <AppendOnly>False</AppendOnly>
  <FillInChoice>False</FillInChoice>
  <HTMLEncode>False</HTMLEncode>
  <Mult>False</Mult>
  <Filterable>True</Filterable>
  <Sortable>True</Sortable>
</Field>
<Field>
   ...
</Field>
```

Comment: I do have the schema attached to the data that I'll be using. I had never used the XmlConvert class. I'm goint to try to see if it will solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I just noticed I had answers on this and no notifications about it. Sorry Eric. You explanation seems coherent. The links though, are no longer valid...

Comment: @MytyMyky Updated the post accordingly, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess I kind of hacked a way around, which works for now. Just replaced the _x***_ charecters for nothing, and corrected the XmlAttributes acordingly. This replacement is done by first loading the xml as a string, then replacing, then loading the "clean" text as XML.

But I wopuld still like to know if it is possible to use some XmlAttribute Name for a more direct approach...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Xml;`  `XmlConvert.EncodeName` and `XmlConvert.DecodeName`

Answer (score 0):

I use a simply function to get the NameCol:

```
private string getNameCol(string colName) {
    if (colName.Length > 20) colName = colName.Substring(0, 20);

    return System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName(colName);
}
```

I'm already searching for replace characters like á, é, í, ó, ú. EncodeName doesn't convert this characters.
Can use Replace:

```
.Replace("ó","_x00f3_").Replace("á","_x00e1_")
```